# AngularJS unbind equivalent variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

Working on a form for a user to edit their details based on a variable on the $rootScope (could also be $scope).

```
$rootScope.formData = $rootScope.user;
```

In the view, there is an ng-model on the input:

```
 ng-model="formData.email"
```

The behavior I expect is to update the model and only $rootScope.formData will update, but instead, both update.

Is there a way to break the relationship between the two?

Comment: The expectation here is wrong. `user` is a reference. Objects in JS are passed as reference. That's it. You can always call clone or cloneDeep (e.g. lo-dash). I would suggest rethink your design based on the fact, that JS behaviour is passing by reference

Comment: You are right and the docs give this exact scenario as the example for angular.copy(). If you make this the answer I will mark it as such. All I had to do was wrap the second var in that method. Thanks. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, we are working with JS references. That means, that we are passing the `user` as reference to the other *(root)* scope

We can call [`angular.copy()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) or [`cloneDeep()`](http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) (see [lo-dash](http://lodash.com/docs)) to work with a new instance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have set one object to another.  Objects are passed by reference in Javascript, so you essentially made `$rootScope.formData` a pointer to `$rootScope.user`.  This is why updating one updates the other.

You could `$rootScope.user = null;`, which would essentially remove the reference, but you have then lost the reference that it had in the first place.  If that is unwanted, I guess you could clone the `user` object into `formData`, which can be a feat in itself if you don't have a library that provides this capability.